# How to retrieve data from one child

Tags: android

In my firebase two child generated one is `"Users"` and second is "Redeem" in users section registration form is saved and points are also saved and in redeem user send data for redeem the points my problem is that when I tried to retrieve data from "Users" then automatically data is merged of "Users" and "Redeem" .maybe this happened because "Users" and "Redeem" have same "UID" of current user now my main point is there is any way to show the data in same activity "Users" and "Redeem" separately in text view.

```
public class redeem extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textname,textemail,textnumber,texttotalpoits;
EditText editname,editemail,editpaytmnumber,editredeempoints,edittotalpoints;
Button submitbtn;

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private  FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private String userID;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.redeem);

    submitbtn = findViewById(R.id.submiybtn);
    textname = findViewById(R.id.textname);
    textemail = findViewById(R.id.textemail);
    textnumber = findViewById(R.id.textnumber);
    texttotalpoits = findViewById(R.id.texttotalpoints);
    editname = findViewById(R.id.editname);
    editemail = findViewById(R.id.editemail);
    editpaytmnumber = findViewById(R.id.editpaytmnumber);
    editredeempoints = findViewById(R.id.editredeempoints);
    edittotalpoints = findViewById(R.id.edittotalpoints);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        }
    };
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = editname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = editemail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String number = editpaytmnumber.getText().toString().trim();
            final String points = edittotalpoints.getText().toString().trim();
            final String redeempoints = editredeempoints.getText().toString().trim();

            if (name.isEmpty()) {
                editname.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email));
                editname.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (email.isEmpty()) {
                editemail.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email));
                editemail.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                editemail.setError(getString(R.string.input_error_email_invalid));
                editemail.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            if (number.isEmpty()) {
                editpaytmnumber.setError("Please Enter Paytm Number");
                editpaytmnumber.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(texttotalpoits.getText().toString());
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(editredeempoints.getText().toString());
            if (number2 > number1){
                editredeempoints.setError("You Have No Enough Points");
                editredeempoints.setText("");
            }
            RedeemInfromation redeemInfromation = new RedeemInfromation(
                    name,
                    email,
                    number,
                    points,
                    redeempoints
            );

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("redeem")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .setValue(redeemInfromation);
        }
    });
}
public void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
        uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getName());
        uInfo.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getEmail());
        uInfo.setNumber(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getNumber());
        uInfo.setPoints(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPoints());

        textname.setText("" + uInfo.getName());
        textemail.setText("" + uInfo.getEmail());
        textnumber.setText("" + uInfo.getNumber());
        texttotalpoits.setText("" + uInfo.getPoints());
        edittotalpoints.setText("" + uInfo.getPoints());

    }

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
}
```

[image: Here is the snapshot of my data in firebase]

Comment: Could you please show the Firebase structure and which data you want to show, Like a screenshot

Comment: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MSjwIkCzBg4/XO0pBLsl5YI/AAAAAAAAFSM/vBIRDNcE7wQ-HB9kyqq1WTT1q0_alVufgCLcBGAs/s1600/g.jpg this is screen shot of realtime data

Comment: simple query on orderBychild(email)

Comment: email,name,number,points and UID is same in both child some time textview show data of "Users" and after input the data of Redeem same textView show the data of "Redeem".

Comment: there is any way to declare that retrieve data only "Users" path?